# show sum of rows below rows in table

Tags: mysql, aggregate, rollup

i have table tblservicesummary

[image]

I have a result set from following query

```
select ss.Quantity as Qty ,ss.Item , ss.ES_ServiceStart as Time, fr.functionRoom from tblServiceSummary ss 
join servdesc sd on ss.Service_time =sd.ServDescID  
join funct fn on fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID 
join tbl_functionRoom fr on fr.id=fn.EvtID
where fn.StartDate between '2018-09-19' and '2018-09-19' 
and ss.Item != ''  
order by ss.Item
```

like this

[image]

I want to display like

[image]

means rows data and sum of rows altogether.

just want to know that is this possible in MySQL? I am not able to achieve with the group by function.

the only related thing I found is rollup function.

I tried

queries like

```
SELECT Quantity, Item, count(Quantity) AS sumoption
FROM tblServiceSummary 
GROUP BY Quantity WITH ROLLUP
```

but that gives me result like

[image]

also tried

```
SELECT Quantity, Item, count(Quantity) AS sumoption
FROM tblServiceSummary 
GROUP BY Quantity WITH ROLLUP
```

please suggest

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us a sample of the rows in your `tblServiceSummary`.

Comment: done ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a union with a "sum - group by item" select and order correspondingly.

```
select '' as Kind, ss.Quantity as Qty, ss.Item as Item,
    ss.ES_ServiceStart as Time, fr.functionRoom
from tblServiceSummary ss 
join servdesc sd on ss.Service_time =sd.ServDescID  
join funct fn on fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID 
join tbl_functionRoom fr on fr.id=fn.EvtID
where fn.StartDate between '2018-09-19' and '2018-09-19' 
and ss.Item != ''  

union

select 'SUBTOTAL', sum(ss.Quantity), ss.Item, '', ''
from tblServiceSummary ss 
join funct fn on fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID 
where fn.StartDate between '2018-09-19' and '2018-09-19' 
and ss.Item != ''  
group by ss.Item

order by Item, Kind
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where fn.StartDate between '2018-09-19' and '2018-09-19' 
and ss.Item != ''

Comment: @NeerajVerma Very right. Now I turned GROUP BY and WHERE around; probably meant to change WHERE into HAVING, but kept it so. You might try both, WHERE+GROUP BY and GROUP BY+HAVING for the fastest.

Comment: if I am removing last 'order by ss.Item, Kind'  then working fine

Comment: `order by ss.Item, 1` probably as Kind is a column label, 1 a column number.

Comment: I got your point, very much satisfied :)  , still is there any chance and sum can be inserted between rows ?

Comment: it says Unknown column 'ss.Item' in 'order clause'

Comment: `ORDER BY 3, 1` then? Sorry I did no real SQL for half a year; I'll edit the answer for column names.